# how to convert minutes to days in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How would you convert a number of minutes to number of days? For instance, number of minutes is 20160. Now how do I get number of days based on that using SQL?

Comment: You don't need an Oracle function for this. It's simple arithmetic. Drink a coffee and think about it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--divide by 60 get the number of hours and then by 24 to get the number of days
select 20160/60/24 as days_from_min 
  from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

You divide:

```
select 20160 / (24 * 60) as num_days
```

This returns a fraction.  You can `floor()` or `round()` to get a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Only for the sake of completeness: here is a way to do it with Oracle functions.  (For people who do not want to just assume that the Earth will continue to rotate at a constant speed for the life of their software.)

```
select extract(day from numtodsinterval(20160,'MINUTE')) days
from   dual;
```

This gives full days only, so it's essentially the same as

```
select floor(20160/(24*60)) days from dual;
```